# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable issue. how do i manage to bypass null statements?

Tags: python

im trying to find the locations in which a tweet was sent from, some people obviously dont have a location setting on their tweets, so im wondering how to bypass the "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" and show a "not identified" answer in its place?

the code i use isL `import json

```
with open('tweets7.txt')as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    for r in data['results']:
        for b in  r['place']:
        print (r['place']['full_name'])
        break
    print r['text']
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a try / catch in this case :)

```
with open('tweets7.txt')as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    for r in data['results']:
        try:
            for b in  r['place']:
                print (r['place']['full_name'])

        except TypeError:
            print("location not identified")

    print r['text']
```

Comment: Dont use `except:` it will hide bugs, use `expect TypeError:`

Comment: Updated with the above :)

Comment: thank you so much for the help, but i still get the issue  " for b in  r['place']:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" :'(

Comment: @andrew If you feel like the answer was helpful don't forget to mark it when you get a moment ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the iterable object exists, you can use:

```py
isinstance(data['results'], list)
isinstance(data.get('results', None), list)
```

If you just want to traverse the data['results'], you can use:

```py
for r in data.get('results', []):
    # Todo: your code
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't rely on the input to adhere to your expected format, perhaps it would be useful to get a warning or at least a less obtuse error message than a `KeyError` or a `NoneType is not iterable`.

```
def get_tweets(filename):
    with open(filename) )as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)
    if 'results' not in data:
        raise ValueError("No 'results' in {0!r}".format(data))
    if data['results'] is None:
        return []
    for r in data['results']:
        if 'place' not in r:
           raise ValueError("No 'place' in {0!r}".format(r))
        if r['place'] is not None:
            for b in  r['place']:
                print('.… Oops, forgot to do anything with b')
            print (r['place']['full_name'])
            break
    if 'text' not in r:
        raise ValueError("No 'text' in {0!r}".format(r))
    print r['text']

get_tweets('tweets7.txt')
```

If you are not used to writing robust code, it may seem alien at first to raise an error at every possible opportunity. The key lesson here is to provide *useful* error reporting to indicate what *exactly* is wrong. You should soon find that this improves code usability and maintainability markedly; instead of an odd nondescript `NoneType` traceback perhaps tens of lines away from where the *actual* problem happened, you get an error immediately, which shows precisely when something wasn't what you expected.

If you think you will be able to handle some of these errors in the calling code, take care to `raise` different errors in each case so that you can decide exactly what `except` handlers you want to implement. (Probably then define your own error hierarchy insted of using Python's generic `ValueError` like I did here.)